Equality test of a hyperbolic expressions
The following article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06673v1 by Ce Xu∗
School of Mathematical Sciences, Xiamen University states the following expression:
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{k^2 \sinh ^2(\pi  k)}=\frac{2 C}{3}-\frac{11 \zeta (2)}{30}$$ Where C is a Catalan constant,I try the following but it is not equal to zero.
    N[NSum[1/(k^2*Sinh[Pi*k]^2), {k, 1, Infinity}, 
    Method -> {"EulerMaclaurin"}, WorkingPrecision -> 40] - 
   N[(2/3)*Catalan - (11/30)*Zeta[2], {Infinity, 40}], {Infinity, 
   40}] == 
   0.06653301600688376

but nummerically it is not true ,Their equality could be verified in another way(I try sum by Maple but I get the same expresion

You have a sign error. It should read: .... - N[(2/3)*Catalan + (11/30)*Zeta[2]

It's a typo in the article, an extra $\pi^2$. The identity after Eq. (4.7) should be: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2\sinh^2(\pi n)} = \frac23 G  -\frac{11}{30}\zeta(2).$$
